# horizon dashboard not work for all-in-one virtualbox centos7 vm node NAT

Tags: virtualbox, centos7, openstack, dashboard, horizon

usually I used NAT for Internet access only, Hostonly private interface for openstack management ip when using packstack, from laptop host access to dashboard is working fine.

Today I directly installed packstack on NAT, from CLI everything works well but except dashboard.

```
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:cb:a7:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
```

I setup up port forward for NAT:

```
127.0.0.1: 2080 to guest 80
```

then I can access to http://127.0.0.1:2080 but not for http://127.0.0.1:2080/dashboard, got error:

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL /dashboard/ was not found on this server.
```

in fact dashboard inside vm also not working,

```
[root@localhost ~(keystone_admin)]# curl http://10.0.2.15/dashboard
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at
[no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred,
and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

So looks like issue is inside node, not on port forwarding.

checked /etc/httpd/conf.d/15-horizon_vhost.conf

```
## Server aliases
ServerAlias 10.0.2.15
ServerAlias localhost
ServerAlias localhost
```

Comment: what does `http://127.0.0.1:2080 ` show you? It should redirect you to the `horizon` login page.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:2080 is for web server page, which is fine. The issue is on  http://127.0.0.1:2080/dashboard which is not working for horizon for centos7 using packstack, it looks like the some networking setting on centos.  Same way when I setup one vm node openstack in ubuntu NAT using devstack, I forward local port 2080 to guest vm 80, then can launch horizon by http://127.0.0.1:2080/dashboard.